# Notational confusion concerning differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I've a question that asks:

> Find the most general solution $Y^t = (y_1, y_2)$ to the linear system:
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{dy^1}{dx}+3\frac{dy^2}{dx} = -4y^1-6y^2, ~ 2\frac{dy^1}{dx}+\frac{dy^2}{dx} = 7y^1+8y^2$

---

What exactly does the power on $y$ mean? Should $y^1$ should be $y_1$ and  $y^2$ should be $y_2$?

Comment: surely this is a typo.

Comment: @user537566 That's a way of indexing things. For example, $v^{(i)}_j$ or just simply $v^i_j$ refers to the i-th v vector's j-th component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases, authors in analysis (like Fleming) choose to index the coordinates of vectors with upper indices, as in
$$\mathbf x = (x^1,\dots,x^n)\in\mathbb R^n.$$
This is because it becomes useful in differential geometry to distinguish between upper and lower indices, and it just so happens that scalars that are the components of a vector require the upper indices. One must always be careful, in this setting, *not* to interpret upper indices as exponentiation.

I think what happened there is the exercise came from a book, or set of notes, that adopted this convention, and the author forgot to change it back to his own practice.